# How to make line string like an elliptical arc in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, spatial

I want to create line string like an elliptical arc using start point and end point but maintain as a line string:

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/introduction-to-sql-server-spatial-data/

Comment: @xXx Thanks. But is there a fastest way to do this because I have thousands of line string to convert.